# GIT file view in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]I'm brand new to visual studio code, but love the features of it, especially the built in GIT features. When I click on the source button however, it lists every single file. Even when initializing a new repository there are over 700 files listed. Is there a way to limit the view of these files to just the ones you are working on in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

Here is the issue is that you have a `node_modules` directory which contains all your third-party dependencies.

These should be described in your `package.json` but shouldn't be committed to your own version control at all.

You need to tell Git to ignore those files.

Create or edit the file `.gitignore` in the root of your project and add `node_modules` to it.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just figured out how to do the .gitignore